# how to click button that performs some ajax opertaions with selenium in php?

Tags: php, selenium

I want to perform click event on a button using selenium and my code is given below and I tried this:

```
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost",4444);
//$ffprofile = $webdriver->prepareBrowserProfile("");
$webdriver->connect("chrome");                            
$webdriver->get("https://healofy.com/"); sleep(3);

$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, "wgt_lang_hn");
if ($element) {
    $element->click();
}
```

but this code is not able to fulfil my requirement. 
I will be thankful if anyone can help; I want to click Hindi button on [this](https://healofy.com/)
site

Comment: Could you try to click on the element 'label'? Actually you're clicking on the element 'input'.

Comment: yes tried but did't work,any other idea please?

Comment: Did you try to debug $element? What if it's null/false? Maybe add an else statement and throw some Exception just to make sure you get an actual element...

Comment: @KasperAgg its not empty it gives me following when i print the $element

Comment: WebElement Object ( [requestURL:protected] => http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/61493ee4a81ceb8c2ac9f0cfe0ad6601/element/0.5483245897948128-1 [_curl:protected] => )

Answer (score 0):

If you try to click the button with the selector given in your example

```
($element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, "wgt_lang_hn");
)
```

it returns that the element is not visible and could not be interacted with. In order to click the button you should click on the element 'label' with attribute 'for', and not on the element 'input' with attribute 'id'.

```
<div class="lang-item">
<input id="wgt_lang_hn" type="radio" value="hi" name="lang_radio"/>
<label for="wgt_lang_hn">हिन्दी</label>
</div>
```

If it still doesn't work - please wait before the click the element to be clickable or visible.

This piece of code works for me (sorry, I'm working with java but you could convert it to php ):

```
 WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for= 'wgt_lang_hn']"));
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@for= 'wgt_lang_hn']")));
 button.click();
```